# Can't pass array from jsp to javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, arrays, jsp

My jsp code and js code are within the same jsp file. I want to send two array to js part. Here is my jsp array:

```
String[] node = call.getAll(results_list[i * 18 + 1]);
int[] edge = call.getAllTable2();
```

Some websites said that I have to receive array at js part like below:

```
var node1 = <%=node%>;
var edge1 = <%=edge%>;
```

But this method could not work. It could only work well on string or int. Is there other method to pass my array?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Like this:

<script language="JavaScript">  

var node1= new Array();  
<%  
for (int i=0; i < node .length; i++) {  
%>  
node1[<%= i %>] = '<%=node [i] %>';
<%}%> 
</script>
```